# Probability an 6 sided die will be higher than a 8 sided die?

Tags: probability, dice

Say one person rolls an 8 sided die and the other rolls a six, what is the probability that the six sided die is higher than the 8?

I know that the expected value of the eight is 4.5 and the six is 3.5 but am having trouble figuring out how to find the probability.

EDIT: Answer is `15/48` but still curious if there's a way of doing this without creating a grid.

Comment: Draw a $6 \times 8$ array and fill it with all the elementary events that can occur (each one with probability $1/48$, assuming equidistribution) then count...

Comment: Ok that'll work, I am curious if there's a simpler way though. What if I'm dealing with numbers too large to draw out? I suppose I could always whip up a script to do it but curious if there's a formula.

Comment: There are cases like this one where no "witty" way exist. One thing is sure, the fact that you know the expected values of the "6" and the "8" dice is of no help for your problem.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for your help

Comment: The result cannot be $120/48$ because it would be $> 1$. It should be $21/48$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I believe it should be $15/48$

Comment: @Skeleton Bow You are perfectly right: $n(n+1)/2=15$ for $n=5$.

Comment: Sorry about the 5!/48 thing. I meant 5+4+3+2+1 and brain farted to 5 factorial.

Comment: The title has the inequality opposite from the question body.  I have supplied answers to both, but you may want to make the title agree with the body of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Probability That The $\boldsymbol{6}$-Sided Die Will Be Higher** (from the body of the question)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^6\overbrace{\frac16}^{k\text{ on d}6}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{k-1}8}^{\lt k\text{ on d}8}
=\frac{5}{16}
$$

---

**Probability That The $\boldsymbol{8}$-Sided Die Will Be Higher** (from the original title to the question)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^7\overbrace{\frac18}^{k\text{ on d}8}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{k-1}6}^{\lt k\text{ on d}6}
+\overbrace{\frac18}^{8\text{ on d}8}\cdot\overbrace{1\vphantom{\frac16}}^{\lt8\text{ on d}6}
=\frac{9}{16}
$$

Comment: Can you explain what you did there? Your answer does not agree with what I (and others) have found.

Comment: It is the **six** sided die that is to score higher.

Comment: Sorry. I read the title. I have amended my answer.

Comment: I made the same "mistake" and deleted, I now see that OP  confused us with conflicting title and body !

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the conflicting title, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d_8$ be the result of the 8-sided die, and $d_6$ the result of the the 6-sided die.

$$P(d_8<d_6) = \sum_{i=1}^6 P((d_8 < d_6) \cap(d_6=i)) = \sum_{i=1}^6 P(d_8 < d_6|d_6=i)\cdot P(d_6=i)$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^6 \frac{i-1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{48}\sum_{i=1}^6 (i-1) = \frac{\frac{6\cdot 7}{2}-6}{48} = \frac{15}{48} = \frac{5}{16}$$

You can generalise for any $n,m$ sided dice. Assume $n>m$ we have:

$$P(d_n<d_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m P((d_n < d_m) \cap(d_m=i)) = \sum_{i=1}^m P(d_n < d_m|d_m=i)\cdot P(d_m=i)$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{i-1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{nm}\sum_{i=1}^m (i-1) = \frac{\frac{m\cdot (m+1)}{2}-m}{nm} = \frac{\frac{m+1}{2}-1}{n} = \frac{\frac{m-1}{2}}{n} = \frac{m-1}{2n}$$

Comment: It could perhaps be more simply  derived as $\frac12$ (total squares minus diagonal squares in smaller die)/(total squares in grid) $= \frac{(m^2-m)/2}{mn} = \frac{m-1}{2n}$

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy. You don't even need a grid. We just have to count the number of tuples $(x,y) ; x \subset A$ and $y\subset B$ [where A is the est of all possible numbers of the six sided dice(1-6) and B is the  set of all possible numbers of the eight sided dice(1-8)] such that $x>y$(by the problem). There are 15 such tuples: 5 for x = 6, 4 for x = 5 so on till 1 for x = 2. Thus the probability is P= $\frac{15}{48}$.
PS: I don't know how your edit makes sense with the probability being $\frac{120}{48}$,which i believe is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_6>X_8) ~=~& \mathsf P(X_8<7)~\mathsf P(X_6>X_8\mid X_8<7)+\mathsf P(X_8>6)~\mathsf P(X_6>X_8\mid X_8>6) \\ ~=~& \frac 68\cdot\frac {15}{36}+\frac 28\cdot 0  \\ ~=~& \frac {5}{16} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> From the OP:
>
> 1. " Say one person rolls an *$8$ sided die* and the other rolls a *six* ".
> 2. " What is the probability that the six sided die
>      $\underline{is\ higher\ than}$ the $8$ ? ".

$$\bbx{\ds{\large%
\mbox{Hereafter,}\ \bracks{\cdots}\ \mbox{is the}\ Iverson\ Bracket}}
$$

---

The *answer* to $2.$ is given by:
\begin{align}
{1 \over 8}\sum_{d_{8} = 1}^{8}{1 \over 6}\sum_{d_{6} = 1}^{6}
\bracks{d_{6} > d_{8}} & =
{1 \over 48}\sum_{d_{8} = 1}^{8}\braces{\bracks{d_{8} \leq 5}
\sum_{d_{6} = d_{8} + 1}^{6}} =
{1 \over 48}\sum_{d_{8} = 1}^{8}\bracks{d_{8} \leq 5}\pars{6 - d_{8}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 48}\sum_{d_{8} = 1}^{5}\pars{6 - d_{8}} =
{1 \over 48}\bracks{5 \times 6 - {5\pars{5 + 1} \over 2}} =
\bbx{\ds{5 \over 16}} = 0.3125
\end{align}

Answer (score -2):

If there is a die with $m$ sides and a die with $n$ sides, assuming that $m<n$, the probability that $m$ will be greater than $n$ assuming that those are the names given to the outcomes when both of them are rolled is

$$\frac{m-1}{2n}$$

Full disclaimer: I made this up with help from the grid. This is a formula very specific to your question.

Comment: I don't think this is a general formula.

Comment: @trueblueanil it is the general formula (look at my answer), I just did not see any explanation on how SkeletonBow arrived there.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question as the $8$ sided die scoring higher. Drat, can't up vote now, so sorry !

Comment: @trueblueanil no problem. I saw your answer (which you deleted), and figured that you thought it was for numbers higher than *or equal to* the ones on the 8-die.

Comment: @Thanassis to be honest, it was quite simple: I drew it out on a grid and realized that every time you add a number to the smaller $m$, the number of possibilities grew by $m-1$. This meant that I needed to find the total sum of the first $m-1$ integers and then divide that by the total number of squares on the grid, which would be $m\cdot n$ and then got the simplified result.